# Rendering ACF Shortcode inside Tag Description

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I wanted to render an acf (Advanced Custom Fields) shortcode inside the tag description. While other shortcodes were rendered successfully, the acf shortcode I added didn’t seem to work. Can someone please help? Thank you so much!

I added [acf field="this_meta_data"] to the tag description but it didn't render.

Answer (score 0):

There has a way to solve this problem
your can write ...

```
do_shortcode([acf field="your_field_name" post_id="your_post_id"]);
```

That is working on my projects;
hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I tried something similar with no luck. I believe I needed to add something like this add_filter('tag_description', 'do_shortcode'); but still no luck.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).